# Add multiple images to the Footer

Tags: wordpress

I did like to add multiple images into the website footer next to my copyrights.
I have tried adding custom css for images but it doesn’t work when I publish.

Comment: Without any information what we can imaging? Please show what code you are using.

Comment: this code is add in custom css

Comment: please tell me any solution to add multiple images in footer next to copyright

Answer (score 0):

Basically your css property is incorrect for image.

use it like this :

```
    .footer-copyright-img {
    background-image: url("yourpath/image_name.jpg")
   }
```

for multiple image use like:

```
 .footer-copyright-img {
background-image: url("yourpath/image_name1.jpg"),
                  url("yourpath/image_name2.jpg");
}
```

Comment: class="copyright footer-copyright"> <a
href="https://abc" class="footer-copyright-link"><img
class="footer-copyright-img" src="https://abc/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/jama.jpg?189db0&amp;189db0"  width="192" height="89" alt="abc" /></a>                                                   that is my source code now i want to add more images using custom css...    i m using kallyas theme in word press